# Does it make sense to normalize/denormalize tree structured data when designing ngrx state?

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, ngrx

I am building a todo application with a list of todos which can also have sub Todos. Before using ngrx my model looked like this:

```
export interface Todo {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  isDone?: boolean;
  parentId?: string;
  subTodos?: [Todo];
}

<todo *ngFor="let todo of todoss$|async">
  <todo *ngFor="let subTodo of todo.subTodos"></todo>
</todo>
```

This was handy for displaying the data inside the view as I was able to use nested `*ngFor`s to do so. Because the reducer logic for updating the sub tasks got a little complicated, I thought about using entities. But normalizing data seems to come with some trade offs. Now I not only have to filter my Todos to remove the sub tasks from the main list, I also have to query the data for every single SubTodo. This seems to be a lot of computation being done for simplifying the update logic.

Model looks like this now:

```
export interface Todo {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  isDone?: boolean;
  parentId?: string;
  subTodos?: [string]; // an Todo.id
}
```

I read a lot about ngrx but was unable to find any example with such a data structure. I'm wondering how would you tackle the problem? Do you always normalize your arrays and split up related models? And if so do you denormalize data when you use it in your views or do you look it up in designated components (which seems ugly to me)? And how do you design the interfaces if so? Do you create two separate interfaces for view model and the state model?

Comment: Did you get the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to still have the same view models as before.

Here is where selectors are coming into play, they can transform your state into a viewmodel that fits your needs the best.